# Why parent no-arg constructor is called?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

```
public class Animal {
    public Animal() { System.out.print("Animal"); }
    public Animal(int age) { System.out.print("AnimalAge"); }
    private boolean hasHorns() { return false; }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Elk(5);
        System.out.println("," + animal.hasHorns());
    }
}

class Elk extends Animal {
    public Elk(int age) { 
        System.out.print("Elk");
    }
    
    public boolean hasHorns() { return true; }
}
```

compiles and I dont understand the output

"Since there is no explicit call to the parent constructor, the default no-argument super() is inserted as the first line of the constructor"

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question with that quote at the end of your post. Is there something else that is not clear?

Comment: the parent class, including fields, is part of the child class; when a child instance is created, the parent part must also be initialized - that is the function of the constructor, so one constructor of the parent class (and of the grand-parents) must be called - as specified, if you do not explicitly call either `this(...)` or `super(...)`, the compiler will include a call to `super()` (unless for an instance of `Object`)

Comment: Java Language Specification [8.8.7. Constructor Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se22/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7): "If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class `Object`, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "`super();`", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments."

Comment: BTW "*I dont understand the output*" is very vague. It would be better to be a bit more verbose, describing what exactly you did not understand, including example of the actual part you did not understand and output you do expect, eventually with reason for that

Comment: BTW2 `Animal.hasHorns()` is declared `private`, so it is **not** being overridden by `Elk.hasHorns()`, so the second one is **not** being called by the `animal.hasHorns()` statement; ergo "false" is being output, **not** "true"